# Цитирование многоточия наряду с пропуском слов

Tags: пунктуация, цитирование, многоточие

*Героиня романа убеждена: «...новое чувство любви к детям и к отцу моих детей положило начало... жизни, которую я ещё не прожила в настоящую минуту...».*

Без источника в руках трудно сказать, что подразумевает то или иное многоточие: умолчание в тексте (полная цитата ниже) или цитатный пропуск. Есть ли средства пунктуации, что могут способствовать пониманию в ходе чтения текста с цитатами? Как они могут улучшить эту?

---

*«С этого дня кончился мой роман с мужем; старое чувство стало дорогим, невозвратным воспоминанием, а новое чувство любви к детям и к отцу моих детей положило начало другой, но уже совершенно иной счастливой жизни, которую я ещё не прожила в настоящую минуту...» (Л. Толстой «Семейное счастие»).*

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=307465